# What is operating temperature of the human brain?

Tags: brain, temperature, death

I've heard several times that human brain can die in temperatures over 40 °C, or under 10 °C, as an engineer I'm curious.

In what temperature region can brain properly work?

And just an underlying question what is a TDP (thermal design power) of human brain?

Comment: What did your research tell you, and how/why did it confuse you?

Comment: @anongoodnurse Most articles on this differ, and I wasn't able to find any that would have sufficient sample size (more than 1) or would be peer reviewed. Also I'm not very good at searching for medical papers, there is a chance I've missed something that would be good.